# Error "dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given"

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, terminal

Running Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon

A while ago a created a script that changed the colors in the Terminal (to match a tutorial I was following)

However if I open the terminal on another account, I get this error:

```
dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given
```

I no longer need the script anymore, so how can I track down where this thing is and get rid of it?

Comment: If its starting with the term, possibly `.bashrc` (if using bash) or in profiles.

Comment: How can I find it?  I'm a Linux noob....

Comment: `.bashrc` should be located in your home directory. Profiles would be `/etc/profiles`. Just go into either file and try to find the `dircolors` var.

Comment: I have no .bashrc file in home, and /etc/profile does not contain `dircolors` in it.  Any other locations?

Answer (score 2):

There are several places where you *could* have used a script besides `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`; without providing details on what changes you made, you will get only general advice.  For instance, you might have

- modified or added a file in `/etc/profile.d`
- modified your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`
- run the terminal via a script (or desktop "launcher")

You can find possible places using grep, e.g.,

```
$ grep -r -l dircolors /etc ~ 2>/dev/null
/etc/profile.d/colorls.csh
/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh
/etc/DIR_COLORS
/etc/DIR_COLORS.lightbgcolor
/etc/DIR_COLORS.256color
```

The error message is from `dircolors` ([see source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/dircolors.c#n465)), which does this when your `SHELL` environment variable is either unset or empty ([see source-code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/dircolors.c#n130) for check).

Comment: Under debian based distros the file can be in /etc/skel/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need dircolors (colorful output from "ls") when SHELL is not set, then wrap your eval dircolors command in an "if".

If you always use /bin/bash, then maybe do like this:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ $SHELL = "/bin/bash" -a -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
    #alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    #alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    #alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```